# CDF and pdf of continuous extension of discrete random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a question concerning the derivation of CDF and pdf of the continuous variable derived from a discrete random variable.

The context is given below (I retyped what the author wrote):

> Given $X$ is a discrete random variable in a subset $A$ of the set $\mathbb{N}$ of the non-negative integers.
> Denote $P(X=x) = f_x$
> We associate $X$ with a continuous random variable $X^*$ such that $X^* = X + (U - 1)$ where $U$ is a continuous random variable valued in $(0,1)$ and is independent of $X$ and $U$ has a strictly increasing cdf $L_U(u)$ on $(0,1)$.
>  We say that $X$ is continued by $U$.
> Then we derive the cdf $F^*$ and pdf $f^*$ of $X^*$.
> Clearly, $X^* \le X$ a.s. Let $[s]$ be the integer part of $s \in \mathbb{R}$.
> For $s \in \mathbb{R}$, we have:
> $$\begin{align}F^*(s) = P(X^* \le s) &=\sum \limits_{x \in A : x \le [s]} f_x+L_U(s - [s]) f_{[s+1]} \\
> &=  F([s])+L_U(s-[s])f_{[s+1]} 
> \tag{1} \end{align}$$
> and
> $$f^*(s) = l_U(s-[s]) f_{[s+1]} \tag{2}$$
> where $f^*$ is the density corresponding to $F^*$ and $l_U$ is the density corresponding to $L_U$

Could you please explain me in more details (step by step) to get from the beginning to the equation (1) and (2) ? The explanation of the author is too dense and I can't understand.

I have try my own derivation to derive $F^*_{\, \, X^*}$ (i.e. the equation (1)) like this:
$$\begin{align}
F^*(s) &= P(X^* \le s) \\
&= P(X + (U - 1) \le s) \\
&= P(U \le (s+1) - X) \\
&= \sum \limits_{X = x: x \le s} P(U \le s + 1 - x | X = x) \times P(X = x) \quad\small\text{, conditioning on } X \\
&= \sum \limits_{X = x: x \le [s]} P(U \le s + 1 - x) \times P(X=x) \quad\small\text{, $X$  and $U$ are independent} \\
&= \sum \limits_{X = x: x \le [s]} L_U(s+1-x) f_X(x)
\end{align}$$

And I see that my result is very different from the equation (1) of the author and I really don't know why. I stopped at (1) and I don't know how to prove (2).

Comment: You're trying to find $P(X+U\le s+1)$. If $X\le [s]$, then $X+U\le s+1$ no matter what $U$ is, but if $X=[s+1]$ then $X+U\le s+1$ if and only if $U \le s - [s]$.